# Is There A Way To Iterate Datagrid Filter Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datagrid

I've been learning to implement a small ROR system, and using a powerful Datagrid gem for filtering, sorting, exporting data, etc.

Today, I've been trying to iterate the filters based on children object.
Let say:
- I have a main Client object which I do the filtering
- Client has and belongs to many Products
- Product has and belongs to many Clients
- Product belongs to Category

In my case:
- Category A has 3 products P1, P2, P3
- Category B has 2 products P4, P5
- Client has 5 products P1, P2, P3, P4 & P5

Currently, I can implement only one Product filter which I retrieve all the products used by the Client.

Buy what I want is to split the products by their Category. So, it should have two Category filters. The problem is that iteration cannot be used in Datagrid class.

I wonder if there is a way like:

```
Category.all.each do |category|
    filter(:category_name, :enum, ...) do |scope|
        ...
    end
end
```